# DeleteRange function in ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-boilerplate

How can I delete a list of entities, without using a loop, in ASP.NET Boilerplate MVC?

Currently, I use:

```
foreach (var data in sampleDataList)
{
    _iRepositorySampleData.Delete(data);
}
```

But I don't want to use a loop to delete multiple entities.

Comment: What is wrong with what you currently doing? Even `RemoveRange()` - or indeed any method that would delete multiple items - is going to have to use a loop internally)

Comment: wrong with my team leader haha I told him like that. and I also want to know if there is some function like RemoveRange in Asp.net Boilerplate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET Boilerplate's `IRepository` does not provide `RemoveRange` out-of-the-box as:

> ASP.NET Boilerplate is designed to be independent from a particular ORM (Object/Relational Mapping) framework or another technique to access a database.<sup>[1](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories#custom-repository-implementation)</sup>

Feature requests in the backlog:

- [IRepository.BulkInsert #648](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/648)
- [Repository methods for multiple entities #1021](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1021)

At the moment, there is not much going for it as it's already possible, so there is little value added.

## EF Core

```
// using Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories;

repository.GetDbContext().RemoveRange(sampleDataList);
```

## EF6

```
// using Abp.EntityFramework.Repositories;

var type = sampleDataList.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
repository.GetDbContext().Set(type).RemoveRange(sampleDataList);
```